# Find PID then end the task

Tags: windows, batch

Please help to correct the script. I want to find the PID then execute the taskkill function to end the task but it shows unexpected error.

```
  for /f "token=2" %%i in ('tasklist /v | find "Counting down..."') do taskkill /pid %%i
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the `/FI` filter argument of taskkill for filtering instead of the non-working `| find ...`? Or take this as a reason to start with powershell, filtering and killing a process using powershell should be way easier.

Comment: ***`| was unexpected at this time. `*** ^Did ˆyou ˆread ˆthe ˆerror ˆand ˆpay ˆattention ˆto ˆit? `|` => `ˆ|`

Comment: @iTwasnTme, I did not realize it. Now I get the point and it works now. Thanks!